# VSCode PHP debugger is not stopping at breakpoints with php cli

Tags: php, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am running a PHP script from the VSCode terminal using `php myscript.php`

I put these lines at the end of my `php.ini` at `/usr/local/etc/php/8.1/php.ini`

```
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = trigger
xdebug.discover_client_host = 1
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20210902/xdebug.so
```

When I had `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` I received this in the console

`Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(`

Most other solutions tell me to put those things in my php.ini

[This is the output from my phpinfo()/php -i](https://gist.github.com/samgermain/b6636d66d11a57d2cf26c618010ff3c2)

**launch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                "-S",
                "localhost:0"
            ],
            "program": "",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 9003,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You should have `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` and start debugging using the "Listen for Xdebug" profile. After that when you run the script from the command line it should stop at your breakpoints.

Comment: @parapente What is the "Listen for Xdebug" profile

Comment: Sorry I meant configuration. In the launch.json you pasted above you have 3 configurations for debugging. If you use the run icon in the activity bar (left sidebar) of VSCode, you should see on the top left that you can select which profile to use and you must press run to activate it.

Comment: @parapente I'm trying to use the command line, how do I select it from there

Comment: I don't think that is possible for the terminal inside vscode or any other terminal. You have to enable and start the debugging process via the GUI and then run the program in the terminal.